# Apache Solr Search proper syntax in url?

Tags: search

Can anyone provide some info on how to properly execute a filtered apache sold search through the url?  So far I've figured out that

```
?fq[]=bundle:type
```

will return a results filtered by that bundle type.  I've also noticed that

```
?f[0]=machine_name:value
```

will return results if that particular facet has been configured.  What I want to figure out, though, is how to use the url to send any filter request.  For example, if I want to write a url that would return results based on a particular taxonomy term, how would I enter that?  Furthermore, can any field be used to filter a search?

Answer (score 0):

You should integrate Updated Apachesolr module. 
Write some custom menu hook to invoke your custom function.

```
 $query = apachesolr_current_query();
 $params_query = $query->getParams();
```

The above two statements will help us to check our solr queryString that we have triggered from our application.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_search_execute().
 */
function Custom_Function($keys = NULL, $conditions = NULL) {

  $filters = isset($conditions['fq']) ? $conditions['fq'] : array();
  $solrsort = isset($_GET['solrsort']) ? $_GET['solrsort'] : '';

  $response = NULL;
    $filt = array();
  // add custom filters if you want to add few custom filters in certain conditions.
   if($_GET['some key'] == 'some condition') {
        $filt[] = array('name' => 'entity_type', 'value' => 'trend_tips');
      }else{
        $filt[] = array('name' => 'im_16_field_category', 'value' => $_GET['category']);
      }
  $filters = $filt;
  $results = apachesolr_search_run('apachesolr', array('q' => $keys, 'fq' => $filters), $solrsort, 'search/' . arg(1), pager_find_page());

    // Set name for search results
    $query = apachesolr_current_query();

    $params_query = $query->getParams();

    if (module_hook($module, 'search_page')) {
      return module_invoke($module, 'search_page', $results); 
    }
 }
/**
 * Implementation of hook_apachesolr_query_prepare().
 */
function CustomeModule_apachesolr_query_prepare(&$current_query) {

  // add query filters for Style tips and trends
  $current_query->addParam('fl', 'tm_image,tm_url,content');
  $current_query->addParam('qf', 'tm_title');
  $current_query->addParam('qf', 'tm_short_content');
  $current_query->addParam('qf', 'tm_perex');
  $current_query->addParam('mm', '1<-90%'); // if you write more then 1 word to search, solr search as 'OR'
  $current_query->addParam('bf', 'recip(rord(created),4,5759,5759)^5.0'); // remove time dependency on search results


  // remove following content types (product and page) from search
    $current_query->addFilter('entity_type', 'product', true);
    $current_query->addFilter('bundle', 'page', true);
    $current_query->addFilter('tid', "63", true);
    $current_query->addFilter('tid', "64", true);


  $current_query->addParam('facet.field', 'bundle'); 
  // add a new facet type for filter trends and tips on search results

}
```

Please let me know if the above codebase helped to get some grip.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might help you using something like the Pretty Paths module
https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_pretty_paths

It will be much easier to construct the urls you want.

[image: screenshot]